# Problems with Mac OS X Leopard Install DVD

Tags: macos, mac, reinstall

I lost my last OS X install disk and Apple kindly sent me (Leopard 10.5 - 2Z61-6037-A) a new one free of charge, however I'm having a problem.

I load in the CD it pops up and the application opens asking me to restart my computer, the computer successfully restarts boot when it comes to the Apple logo it just gets suck and comes up with the Kernel Panic restart box (see below).

[image: Kernel Panic]

Can anyone tell me what's happening/if it can be resolved or should I go back to Apple and explain the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you've got a bad CD. Obviously check for scratches that might have occurred in transit when they shipped it to you. Other than trying to use some of the scratch removing gel, your best bet is to call Apple and ask for another CD.

Comment: their were a few, I that might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting up holding the 'v' or 'cmd+v' keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try a new DVD, but that looks pretty serious - it's usually a hardware fault, I assume it's the DVD drive.

Try cleaning the drive, and try either copying a disk to test it or using The Apple Extended Hardware test (reboot with system disk in drive and hold down 'd' key).